# For a $2$ by $2$ matrix A, why does $A^3=0$ imply $A^2=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

The field is not specified and $0$ in the question means the $2$ by $2$ zero matrix.

I have a feeling this is something to do with the minimal polynomial of A, but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the field is not specified then this is clearly false. It obviously fails for complex matricies, for example; consider $A=e^{2\pi i/3}I$.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich With this choice of $A$, $A^3=e^{2 \pi i}I=I$ and not $0$...

Comment: Eewps. Sorry...

Comment: It does have "to do with the minimal polynomial of $A$".  You are almost there!  (Minimal polynomial must divide....)